# Getting corresponding value from list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list in Python and I would like to get the corresponding value.

```
month_days = [('January', [31]), ('February', [28, 29]), ('March',[31])]
```

I would like to enter for example `Jan` and get the number of days as is in the list.

For example:

```
send_days('March')
```

Comment: Also if you wan't a look up feature, maybe look into `dictionaries`.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I just want to enter "March" and get 31

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) instead of a list of tuples.

But with your current code you could use this:

```
month_days = [('January', [31]), ('February', [28, 29]), ('March',[31])]


def send_days(m):

    for x in month_days:
        if x[0] == m:
            return x[1]

send_days('January')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list actually looks like:

```
month_days = [('January', [31]), ('February', [28, 29]), ('March',[31])]
```

You can convert it into a dictionary:

```
month_dict = dict(month_days)
```

and then query the dictionary with month names:

```
>>month_dict['February']
[28, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is either a dictionary or a named tuple. You can read up on both [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)